# Custom flume sink: channel.takeEvent() always null

Tags: cloudera-cdh, flume-ng

I need a flume sink to write events to kudu, so I implemented my own Kudu sink. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.flume.Channel;
import org.apache.flume.Context;
import org.apache.flume.Event;
import org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException;
import org.apache.flume.Transaction;
import org.apache.flume.conf.Configurable;
import org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractSink;
import org.kududb.client.Insert;
import org.kududb.client.KuduClient;
import org.kududb.client.KuduSession;
import org.kududb.client.KuduTable;
import org.kududb.client.PartialRow;
import org.kududb.client.SessionConfiguration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author cespedjo
 */
public class CustomKuduSink extends AbstractSink implements Configurable{

    private static final String KUDU_TABLE_COLUMNS_CSV = "kudu.columns";

    private static final String KUDU_MASTER_SERVER = "kudu.masterserver";

    private static final String KUDU_DATABASE = "kudu.database";

    private static final String KUDU_COLUMNS_TYPE_CSV = "kudu.columnstype";

    private static final String KUDU_EVT_HEADER_KEYS = "kudu.headerKeys";

    private static final String KUDU_MAX_EVENTS = "kudu.maxEvents";

    private String tableName;

    private String[] columns;

    private String kuduMaster;

    private String[] columnsTypes;

    private String[] evtheaderKeys;

    private KuduClient kuduClient;

    private KuduTable table;

    private int maxEvents;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(CustomKuduSink.class);

    public static final String SESION_ID = "sesionId";
    public static final String PANTALLA = "pantalla";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP_CLIENTE = "timestampCliente";
    public static final String ENTIDAD = "entidad";
    public static final String ROW_KEY = "rowKey";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String TARGET = "target";
    public static final String ACCION = "accion";
    public static final String IP = "ip";
    public static final String USERAGENT = "userAgent";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP_SERVIDOR = "timestampServidor";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_PAGINAORIGEN = "contenido$paginaOrigen";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_DURACION = "contenido$duracion";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_USERNAME = "contenido$username";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_USERTYPE = "contenido$usertype";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_LABEL = "contenido$label";
    public static final String CONTENIDO_VALUE = "contenido$value";

    @Override
    public Status process() throws EventDeliveryException {
        Status status = Status.READY;
        boolean readyForClose = false;

        Channel ch = getChannel();
        Transaction txn = ch.getTransaction();
        txn.begin();

        try {
            LOG.info("Taking event from channel... ");

            Event evt = ch.take();

            if (evt == null) {
                LOG.info("Event is null... ");
                //status = Status.BACKOFF;
            } else {
                LOG.info(evt.getHeaders().toString());

                Insert insert = table.newInsert();
                PartialRow row = insert.getRow();

                Map<String, String> headers = evt.getHeaders();
                KuduSession session = kuduClient.newSession(); 
                session.setFlushMode(SessionConfiguration.FlushMode.AUTO_FLUSH_SYNC);
                session.setTimeoutMillis(10000);

                for (int i = 0; i < this.columns.length; ++i) {
                    String aType = this.columnsTypes[i].trim();
                    String aColumn = this.columns[i].trim();
                    String value = headers.get(this.evtheaderKeys[i]);

                    LOG.info("column: " + aColumn + ",type: " + aType + ", value:" + value);
                    if (aType.equalsIgnoreCase("BIGINT"))
                        row.addLong(aColumn, value != null && !value.isEmpty() ?
                                Long.parseLong(value) :
                                -9999999999L);
                    if (aType.equalsIgnoreCase("STRING"))
                        row.addString(aColumn,
                                value == null || value.isEmpty() ? "NA" : value);
                    if (aType.equalsIgnoreCase("INT"))
                        row.addInt(aColumn, value != null && !value.isEmpty() ?
                                Integer.parseInt(value) :
                                -999999);
                    if (aType.equalsIgnoreCase("DECIMAL"))
                        row.addDouble(aColumn, value != null && !value.isEmpty() ?
                                Double.parseDouble(value) :
                                -99999.99);
                }

                session.apply(insert);

                LOG.info("Flushing... " + session.hasPendingOperations());
                session.close();
            }

            readyForClose = true;
            txn.commit();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            LOG.error(t.getMessage());
            LOG.error(Arrays.toString(t.getStackTrace()));
            status = Status.BACKOFF;
            txn.rollback();
            readyForClose = true;

            if (t instanceof Error)
                throw (Error)t;
        } finally {
            if (readyForClose) {
                txn.close();
            } else {
                txn.rollback();
                txn.close();
            }
        }

        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        try {
            this.kuduClient = new KuduClient.KuduClientBuilder(this.kuduMaster)
                    .build();
            this.table = kuduClient.openTable(this.tableName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
        } finally {
            super.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stop() {
        super.stop();
        try {
            this.kuduClient.close();
            this.kuduClient.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            LOG.error(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(Context context) {
        String columnsCsv = context.getString(KUDU_TABLE_COLUMNS_CSV);
        this.columns = columnsCsv.split(",");
        this.tableName = context.getString(KUDU_DATABASE);
        this.kuduMaster = context.getString(KUDU_MASTER_SERVER);
        String columnsTypesCsv = context.getString(KUDU_COLUMNS_TYPE_CSV);
        this.columnsTypes = columnsTypesCsv.split(",");
        String headerKeys = context.getString(KUDU_EVT_HEADER_KEYS);
        this.evtheaderKeys = headerKeys.split(",");
        this.maxEvents = context.getInteger(KUDU_MAX_EVENTS, 100);
    }
```

I have three sources, three memory channels and three sinks. HDFS and AsyncHbase sinks get events, but this custom made sink isn't able to capture the events, even though sources inject events into each channel. Please help.

Comment: Which is the configuration you are using for testing this custom sink? Which are the logs taken when running such a configuration?

Comment: I did it and found the error... it was related to my web server. The sink is functioning properly. Thanks for your comment @frb